# Automate Object Creation With Chef Scripts

Tags: chef-infra, ibm-mq

I have my subscriber and publisher applications all up and running in my local environment using IBM MQ in a Docker instance and now need to create my IBM MQ objects- Queue Manager, Queues, Topics, Subscriptions- on QA and higher environments using Chef scripts.

My company already has the code in place to create the Queue Managers but isn't currently using the other object types and I can't find any documentation using duckduckgo or google.

Can someone please point me to some good documentation and/or give examples?

Note: It's the topic and subscriptions I need. I have the code for creating queues:

```
  ibm_mq_qlocal "#{qmgr_name}::Q.MyQueue" do
    qlocal_name 'Q.MyQueue'
    qmgr qmgr_name
  end
```

Comment: Do you want to create the objects directly in a chef script or are you happy to create an MQSC script with all the object definitions in it and then run that from the chef script?

Comment: Ideally I'd go for the chef script because I believe that's what's required. I thought of doing it with a shell script of some kind but I don't if it's allowed.

Is an MQSC script the best solution you think?

Comment: It looks like an MQSC script is the approach we're going to go with for now.

Comment: That's the only way I've seen, but I'm not a chef expert. MQSC script has the advantage that it will always be up-to-date with whatever MQ can do.